# Create nested dictionary from keys seperated by dot(.) in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a requirement where I have a keys in string format combined by dot(.) and the value associated with that string of key and I want to create a dictionary.

```
key1 = "A.B.C.D"
text_to_be_inserted1_for_key1 = "Test1"
key2 = "A.B.C.E"
text_to_be_inserted_for_key2 = "Test2"
```

Expected result

```
dict = {
    "A": {
        "B" : {
            "C" : {
                "D" : text_to_be_inserted1_for_key1,
                "E" : text_to_be_inserted_for_key2 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572347/13890216

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve for each case and then merge

```
from copy import deepcopy

def dict_of_dicts_merge(x, y):
    z = {}
    overlapping_keys = x.keys() & y.keys()
    for key in overlapping_keys:
        z[key] = dict_of_dicts_merge(x[key], y[key])
    for key in x.keys() - overlapping_keys:
        z[key] = deepcopy(x[key])
    for key in y.keys() - overlapping_keys:
        z[key] = deepcopy(y[key])
    return z

key1 = "A.B.C.D"
text_to_be_inserted_for_key1 = "Test1"
key2 = "A.B.C.E"
text_to_be_inserted_for_key2 = "Test2"

dict1 = {}
newdict = {}
olddict = {}
keys_for_1 = key1.split(".")
keys_for_1.reverse()


olddict[keys_for_1[0]] = text_to_be_inserted_for_key1

for i in range (1,len(keys_for_1)):
    newdict = {}
    newdict[keys_for_1[i]] = olddict
    olddict = newdict

save1 = newdict 

newdict = {}
olddict = {}
keys_for_2 = key2.split(".")
keys_for_2.reverse()
olddict[keys_for_2[0]] = text_to_be_inserted_for_key2

for i in range (1,len(keys_for_2)):
    newdict = {}
    newdict[keys_for_2[i]] = olddict
    olddict = newdict 

save2 = newdict

dict1 = dict_of_dicts_merge(save1,save2)
print (dict1)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def deep_dict():
    return defaultdict(deep_dict)

result = deep_dict()

def deep_insert(key, value):
    d = result
    keys = key.split(".")
    for subkey in keys[:-1]:
        d = d[subkey]
    d[keys[-1]] = value

deep_insert("A.B.C.D", "Test1")
deep_insert("A.B.C.E", "Test2")

import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Comment: Im a big fan of avoiding the duplicate -1 indexing if possible, so I believe you could do the same thing more elegantly via by using the splat unpacking feature.


`*keys, final = key.split(".")`

`for subkey in keys:`

`d = d[subkey]`

`d[final] = value`

Answer (score 2):

You may

- for each letter except the last one, create a mapping with the key and a `dict`
- for the last letter create the mapping with the value

```
def insert(keys, values):
    res = {}
    for k, v in zip(keys, values):
        res_tmp = res
        levels = k.split(".")
        for level in levels[:-1]:
            res_tmp = res_tmp.setdefault(level, {})
        res_tmp[levels[-1]] = v
    return res
```

Use

```
key1 = "A.B.C.D"
value_key1 = "Test1"
key2 = "A.B.C.E"
value_key2 = "Test2"

result = insert([key1, key2], [value_key1, value_key2])

print(result) # {'A': {'B': {'C': {'D': 'Test1', 'E': 'Test2'}}}}
```