# Possible to set a Python nested dictionary item using single dot-delimited string path?

Tags: python, dictionary, path

I'd like to be able to set a nested dictionary item using a single dot-delimited string path. For example, given the following dictionary:

```
data_dictionary = {
  "user_data": {
    "first_name": "Some",
    "last_name": "Guy",
    "phone": "212-111-1234"
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to set a specific item using a single string, something like this:

```
data_dictionary['user_data.phone'] = '818-333-4567'
```

Anyone know of a library or simple technique for accomplishing something like this?

Comment: If you're constructing the data_dictionary yourself, you could just have unpack the nested dictionaries into the outer dict with those keys.

Comment: You could write a function to split the string and recursively lookup the keys.

Comment: Parse the path & split it by `.`. then traverse the dict using the components till the penultimate component. Finally do a standard assignment using the final key.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463329/4985099

Comment: Using a dataclass for your data might be a good choice, if you want attribute access (dot notation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a little helper function:

```
def set(obj, path, value):
    *path, last = path.split(".")
    for bit in path:
        obj = obj.setdefault(bit, {})
    obj[last] = value

set(data_dictionary, "user_data.phone", "123")
data_dictionary
# {'user_data': {'first_name': 'Some', 'last_name': 'Guy', 'phone': '123'}}
```

You can also subclass `dict` and override `__setitem__`:

```
class my_dict(dict):
  def __setitem__(self, item, value):
    if "." in item:
      head, path = item.split(".", 1)
      obj = self.setdefault(head, my_dict())
      obj[path] = value
    else:
      super().__setitem__(item, value)

dd = my_dict({
    "user_data": {
        "first_name": "Some",
        "last_name": "Guy",
        "phone": "212-111-1234"
    }
})

dd["user_data.phone"]  = "123"
dd
# {'user_data': {'first_name': 'Some', 'last_name': 'Guy', 'phone': '123'}}
```

Comment: Your initial 'set' function works exactly as I had hoped so thanks for that!  I did actually prefer your suggestion of the my_dict subclass (it feels cleaner to me) but it broke down on a nested dictionary when I tried to add a further "address": {"line1": "xxx", "line2": "yyy"}. I've been playing with it to try and make it work. I'll update if I have time to fix.

Comment: this is great! I'm getting an error with `*path, last = path.split(".")` though saying `SyntaxError: ("required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input '*'", ('<input>', 2, 4, '    *path, last = path.split(".")\n'))`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something more friendly for nested structures such as [Box](https://pypi.org/project/python-box/)

Then you can just use `dot` notation to access as many nests as you want:

```
from box import Box

data = Box(data_dictionary)
data.user_data.phone = '818-333-4567'
print(data.user_data.phone)
```

---

```
818-333-4567
```

Comment: I see why, I must have mis-interpreted the question. I have edited with a more appropriate answer.