# Why does the dictionary seem to change between the last statement in the function and the first statement after the function call?

Tags: python, dictionary

In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572347/14277722) to convert a dot notation string to a nested dictionary and set a value, I coudn't understand why the desired result was achieved. Line 4 in particular didn't look right. So I tried

```py
obj, path, value = {}, 'test.test1', 10
*path, last = path.split(".")
for bit in path:
    obj = obj.setdefault(bit, {})
obj[last] = value

print(obj)
```

Output

```
{'test1': 10}
```

This confirmed my suspicions as the expected result is `{'test': {'test1': 10}}`.

But when the code (added `print` statements to see what is happening) runs inside a function the dictionary changes to the desired result only outside the function call.

```py
def setv(obj, path, value):
    *path, last = path.split(".")
    for bit in path:
        obj = obj.setdefault(bit, {})
    print(obj)
    obj[last] = value
    print(obj)

obj, path, value = {}, 'test.test1', 10
setv(obj, path, value)
print(obj)
```

Output

```
{}                      # inside the function call
{'test1': 10}           # inside the function call
{'test': {'test1': 10}} # after the function call
```

What subtle difference am I missing here that explains this behavior?

Comment: In "setv", "obj" is a local variable containing the innermost dict at the end. The global "obj" contains the root dict which is modified in "setv".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `setv`, at the time it is printed, `obj` is a local variable, because there was an assignment `obj = ...`.

The assignment shadows the global variable (or the argument, they are identical) `obj`.

You can verify it by printing `id(obj)` as well.

The fact that the global `obj` is a dictionary that contains a reference to the local `obj` makes this more confusing but doesn't actually matter. The same can be observed with simpler objects:

```
>>> def f(a):
...     print(a)
...     a = 7
...     print(a)
...

>>> a = 10
>>> f(a)
10
7
>>> print(a)
10
```

Comment: I actually missed the changing reference after the assignment. Confirmed by changing `d = obj.setdefault(bit, {}); d[last] = value` in my first example, which gives the expected result.